# Azure Java Deployment via FTP not Unpacking

Tags: java, azure, deployment, ftp

I create a Web App in Azure and upload my war file via FTP into `webapps/my.war`. It is unpacked and deployed successfully. Next time I upload a new version of `my.war`, overwriting the existing file, it's like 50/50 that it will be unpacked and deployed. When it fails for the first time, I find no way to get it back other than deleting the webapp and create a new one.

I have tried all ways I can think off with combinations of stopping the webapp before uploading or not, removing the files `webapps/my` and `webapps/my.war` or not etc.

Why is this and how can I fix it? I mean, the PAAS should just work out of the box, so I must be doing some basic things wrong.

I forgot to mention I am using latest version of Tomcat 8.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a feature of Tomcat, not a mistake for Tomcat on Azure, so it's not necessary to fix anything. According to the Tomcat offical document for [Deploying on a running Tomcat server](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server), there is an explaination for this case as below.

[image]

On Windows, the anti-locking features are enabled. Please refer to the document for [Context Configuration](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation) to know the effectsof `antiResourceLocking=true` in the `conf/context.xml` of Tomcat 8.0.

[image]

You need to restart your webapp to make Tomcat delete the old version for updating, or manuall delete them on Tomcat shutdown.

Comment: Nice catch! However, stopping the webapp before uploading the new war file seems not to be enough. Best result so far is to stop the webapp and wait for 10 seconds before uploading the new version. As I am setting up an automated deployment, this way is not really good, as I need to know for sure it will work each time. Waiting for 10 seconds is more like hoping for the best. Anyway, I guess there's not much I can do about it?

Comment: @Johan Actually, you can upload a tomcat instance to the path `wwwroot` of Azure WebApp via FTP or Kudu Console, then follow the offical tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-custom-upload#application-configuration-examples to configure `web.config` file to enable IIS to startup your custom tomcat.